# AngularJS popover: hide popover template on mouse out

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I am using **AngularJS' ui-bootstrap module**. Here's my **markup:**

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button"
    popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl"
    popover-trigger="click" id="custom_overview"
    popover-placement="bottom">Custom</button>
```

Here's my **controller:**

```
$scope.dynamicPopover = {
    templateUrl : '../static/templates/popup-templates/datepicker.html'
};
```

Here's my **popover template:**

```
<div class="row" id="datepicker-container">
    <div class="col-sm-12 clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <span class="heading">From:</span>
            <input ng-model="timedata.fromDate" type="text" id="fromDate"
                class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy"
                is-open="fromOpen.isOpen" ng-click="fromOpen.isOpen = true" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top:5px">
            <span class="heading">To:</span>
            <input ng-model="timedata.toDate" type="text" id="toDate"
                class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy"
                is-open="toOpen.isOpen" ng-click="toOpen.isOpen = true" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy">
                <div class="error"
                    ng-show="timedata.toDate <= timedata.fromDate && timedata.fromDate && timedata.toDate">
                    <span>'To' date cannot be less than 'From' date.</span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="submit-button">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setInterval('custom')"
            ng-disabled="timedata.toDate <= timedata.fromDate || !timedata.toDate || !timedata.fromDate">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I am populating a popover with a popover template which contains a form. Here's a **screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot of popover]

This popover opens up when I click on the 'Custom' button. Now, I want this popover to hide when I take the mouse away from the template and the 'Custom' tab. How can I do it?

Comment: But the mouse won't be over the template when you click the 'Custom' tab...

Comment: Ok, then hide it when it is away from both 'custom' tab and template?

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but if anyone is stuck on this or any similar problem, here is the simple angularjs popover example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/IkZ0GVVkZCkvugyvrHFB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In short,
replacing **popover-trigger="click"** by **popover-trigger="'mouseleave : click'"** should work for you.

For more understanding,
As per uib-popover [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), both popover open and close triggers will be enabled by default with the popover-trigger attribute(only if you want to close and open on same event).

For example:

1. popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" This by default should open the popover on mouseover and close the popover on mouseleave
2. popover-trigger="'click'" - This will show and hide on clicks
3. In your case(show and close on different events), popover-trigger attribute should contain both events in order to work.

**popover-trigger="'mouseleave : click'"** This should work. Here first and second values represents hide and show triggers respectively.